# why does df.diff give me NaN in the 4 th column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diff

I have the following code:

```
# create dataframes for the lists of arrays (df_Avg_R), list of maxima 
    # (df_peaks) and for the inter-beat-intervals (df_ibi)
    df_Avg_R = pd.DataFrame(Avg_R_val)
    df_idx_max = pd.DataFrame(idx_of_max)
    # delete first and last maxima
    df_idx_max.drop([0, 11], axis=1, inplace=1)
    df_ibi = df_idx_max.diff(axis=1)
```

df_idx_max is the following dataframe (only the first rows):

```
         1    2    3      4      5      6      7      8      9   10
0    55   92  132  181.0  218.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
1    84  140  198  235.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
2    47   64  103  123.0  185.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
3    58  102  146  189.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
4    53   96  139  182.0  201.0  225.0  251.0    NaN    NaN NaN
5    46   89  131  173.0  215.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
6    67  121  161  175.0  231.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
7    52  109  165  206.0  220.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
8    80  135  191  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
9    38   83  139  188.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
10   33   73  113  161.0  205.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
11   54   81  126  153.0  180.0  204.0  251.0    NaN    NaN NaN
12   44   64  116  160.0  206.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
13   56  109  165  220.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
14   43  100  124  155.0  211.0  251.0    NaN    NaN    NaN NaN
```

however the command df_ibi = df_idx_max.diff(axis=1) gives me NaN in all the
4th column of the df_ibi

```
  1     2     3   4     5     6     7     8     9   10
0   NaN  37.0  40.0 NaN  37.0  33.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
1   NaN  56.0  58.0 NaN  16.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2   NaN  17.0  39.0 NaN  62.0  66.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
3   NaN  44.0  44.0 NaN  62.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
4   NaN  43.0  43.0 NaN  19.0  24.0  26.0   NaN   NaN NaN
5   NaN  43.0  42.0 NaN  42.0  36.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
6   NaN  54.0  40.0 NaN  56.0  20.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
7   NaN  57.0  56.0 NaN  14.0  31.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
8   NaN  55.0  56.0 NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
9   NaN  45.0  56.0 NaN  63.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
10  NaN  40.0  40.0 NaN  44.0  46.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
11  NaN  27.0  45.0 NaN  27.0  24.0  47.0   NaN   NaN NaN
12  NaN  20.0  52.0 NaN  46.0  45.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
13  NaN  53.0  56.0 NaN  31.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
14  NaN  57.0  24.0 NaN  56.0  40.0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
```

Do you know why this happens? Thanks

Comment: check the `dtype` of your columns

Comment: the dtype of df_idx_max gives me int64 for the first three columns and float 64 for the other columns, and the dtype of df_ibi gives me float64 for all columns.

Comment: yep - notice where that `dtype` changes and where your error is occurring

Comment: I tried to change the dataframe type by the df_idx_max.astype('float64') however it hasnt worked out. How do I change the type of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is something like a bug, look at this [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10907). You can use the following code to temporarily overcome this problem:

```
df.T.diff().T
```

With your data should be:

```
df_idx_max.T.diff().T
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your entire dataframe to floats, it should work without a problem:

```
df_idx_max = df_idx_max.astype(float, errors='ignore')

df_ibi = df_idx_max.diff(axis=1)
```